Sampling distribution for "most recent k partners"
I'm trying to develop a Bayesian model of how partnerships form / end within a population stratified into groups. The challenge: we only have data (group membership, duration, and if the partnership is ongoing) for the most recent $k=3$ partners (in a non-representative sample - but that's another story). Here is what I have so far (question at the end):

Let $N_i$ be the true population size of group $i$.
Let $f_{ij}$ be the mean per-person rate of partnerships formed by individuals in group $i$ with those in group $j$.

Then $F_{ij} = f_{ij} N_i = f_{ji} N_j$ is the total rate of partnerships forming at the population level, which is symmetric (though $f_{ij}$ is not).


Let $d_{ij}$ be the mean duration of partnerships among groups $i$ and $j$ (which must be symmetric).

Then $X_{ij} = f_{ij} d_{ij}$ is the expected number of active partnerships with $j$ for each individual in group $i$.



Question: For an individual in group $i$, how can we define the probability distribution $\theta_{j|i,k}$ from which which the group index $j$ for the "most recent" $k=3$ partners would be drawn?
Hypothesis: Is it simply:
$j~\sim~\theta_{j|i,k} = \frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_j X_{ij}}$
which does not depend on $k$? I also worry this does not use any information about whether the partnership is / not ongoing.
